# Programmatically hide incomplete elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way I could hide all elements on a page whose bounding box is not completely visible.

I have list of table rows, where the containing element has a dynamic height, but with overflow hidden.

Sometimes half of an item in a list overlaps the containing element boundaries, and I  was hoping either through CSS or JavaScript that I can hide these.

Hopefully, an image can explain this better. Here, I'd like to hide box 24.

[image: overlapping element]

One idea I have is to iterate over all elements, find its bounds, and check if they overlap the container bounds. This seems quite a heavyweight and messy way of doing it (especially as this is a scrolling list, and I'd have to calculate this every second). Is there a better way?

Thanks, and let me know if I need to clarify anything?

**Update:**

I'd like this to be generic and work with different markup structures, but for a simple example of the code I'm using (in this case, I guess only the first would be shown):

```
<style>
  #parent {height: 100px; overflow: hidden; }
  .child {height: 75px;}
</style>

<div id='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code so we can see what we are working with

Comment: Not quite what you are asking but you could overlay a transparent png that adds a fade effect to the bottom of the list? Just a thought

Comment: @DavidNguyen Added some example code

Comment: @dtt101 Good idea, I may just resort to that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the `top offset + height` and check if the resulting value is greater than the container height. If it does, that element and the rest of the items after it are beyond the bounds of the container.

Comment: Would this be `$('.child').position().top + $(.child').height() > $('#parent').height()` using jQuery (and ignoring that `.child` would yield more than one element)?

Comment: @Adam regarding position, correct. For the child height, I suggest using [`.outerHeight(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) to include any margin, border and padding. As for the parent, you need to get the height and padding as well since content in a container with padding will still show the overflowing content until the border.

Answer (score 0):

I think the offsetHeight of the container gives you its real height, so cou can compare to the offsetTop+offsetHeight of each row, to finally hide it if necessary. Just an idea... Maybe some adjustments will be necessary depending on how many parents containers the rows have.

Comment: Yeah, that could work. What do you mean about having many parent containers?

Comment: well for example, if the row has a parent which is a grid, and then the grid would have a parent which would be the main container, then you maybe have to add the top position of the grid to the total to have the real height. (didn't check what offsetTop really returns)

Comment: I see what you mean. That would complicate things.. Ok. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After playing for a moment with `document.elementFromPoint` in http://jsfiddle.net/VhShD/, I think this is just not very good idea.

A better approach would be limit scrolling to certain increments, so that anytime you scroll it will minimally scroll so at least 1 new item is fully shown or hidden. This is used in WinAmp playlists at least.

Unfortunately the `scroll` event sucks, it doesn't contain any information where the user wanted to scroll or ability to prevent the scroll from happening. You'd have to use a completely custom scroll solution like jScrollPane.

Comment: The problem is that I might be displaying 100 items, with a box that could hold around 10, but I can't exactly set the height of the container. I am scrolling in increments, but the 11th might still peek through. As for the scroll, I'm actually using `margin-top` to scroll the list.

Comment: @Adam what do you mean by scrolling in increments but `11th` might still peek through? If the list elements are all same height as the picture suggests, then that shouldn't be possible

Comment: The list elements are fixed height, say 20px, but the container can be anything, for example 33px. Does that make any sense?

Comment: @Adam I see. And the container cannot be resized to match increments? (20px or 40px etc.. in that example)

Comment: Ideally not. I'd like it to be quite generic, and I envisage a scenario where one selected row slightly bigger.